# Gazebo 7, Ambulance model (and other) Invalid mesh filename extension crash

Tags: gazebo-model, mesh, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I installed Gazebo 7 and then downloaded models from https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/downloads/and placed them inside ~/.gazebo/models/ (because gazebo refuses to automatically download any models).

Many of the models work just fine but there is a group of them that refuses to be placed in a world and will in result crash gazebo. In the gazebo log it looks like this:

```
ros@ros-U44SG:~$ gazebo --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.0.0
Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.0.0
Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.102
[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.102

[Err] [MeshManager.cc:96] Invalid mesh filename extension[/home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj]
[Err] [Visual.cc:2021] Unable to create a mesh from /home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj
[Err] [Visual.cc:352] Ogre Error:OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource /home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[Err] [Visual.cc:353] Unable to create a mesh from /home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj
//3x (...)

[Err] [MeshManager.cc:96] Invalid mesh filename extension[/home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj]
[Err] [MeshShape.cc:72] Unable to load mesh from file[/home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj]

[Err] [MeshManager.cc:96] Invalid mesh filename extension[/home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj]
[Err] [Visual.cc:2021] Unable to create a mesh from /home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj
[Err] [Visual.cc:352] Ogre Error:OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource /home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[Err] [Visual.cc:353] Unable to create a mesh from /home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj

[Err] [MeshManager.cc:96] Invalid mesh filename extension[/home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj]
[Err] [Visual.cc:2021] Unable to create a mesh from /home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj

Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::FileNotFoundException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource /home/ros/.gazebo/models/ambulance/meshes/ambulance.obj in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
ros@ros-U44SG:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18014/gazebo-7,-ambulance-model-(and-other)-invalid-mesh-filename-extension-crash/) by [Multiplexer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4192/multiplexer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Those files use `OBJ` meshes, and support for that was added from Gazebo 7.4.0, as you can see on the [Changelog](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/Changelog.md).

Follow the instructions [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=install_ubuntu&ver=7.0#Alternativeinstallation:step-by-step) to update to the latest Gazebo 7 release.

In any case, Gazebo shouldn't crash when trying to load unsupported mesh files, so I ticketed an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2380/should-not-crash-when-trying-to-load) about this.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Multiplexer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4192/multiplexer/) on 2017-12-05**:
thank you, updated to 7.9 successfully and model works now